# JuliaでIjuliaが使えなくなってしまった原因がわからない

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

いままで、Juliaでusing Ijuliaとしていたら、使えるようになっていたのに急に使えなくなってしまいました。原因が全くわかない状況です。
丸投げな質問ですいません。。
自分のノートパソコンはwindows10なのですが、Jupyterを一度終了させ、もう一度ターミナルから起動させようとしたら、このような状況に陥ってしまいました。環境変数も何も変えていません。さらに以前は何回もjupyterを起動できたのですが、、、。
パソコンに詳しい方、ご指導のほどお願いいたします。。

```
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.0.2 (2018-11-08)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> import Pkg

julia> Pkg.build("Ijulia")
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * Ijulia (not found in project or manifest)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(::String) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Types.jl:120
 [2] #ensure_resolved#43(::Bool, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Types.jl:898
 [3] ensure_resolved at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Types.jl:868 [inlined]
 [4] #build#53(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:452
 [5] build at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:433 [inlined]
 [6] build(::String) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:428
 [7] top-level scope at none:0

julia> Pkg.add("Ijulia")
  Updating registry at `C:\Users\reisa\.julia\registries\General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * Ijulia (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(::String) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Types.jl:120
 [2] #ensure_resolved#43(::Bool, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Types.jl:898
 [3] #ensure_resolved at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [4] #add_or_develop#13(::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:59
 [5] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [6] #add_or_develop#12 at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:29 [inlined]
 [7] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [8] #add_or_develop#11 at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:28 [inlined]
 [9] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [10] #add_or_develop#10 at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:27 [inlined]
 [11] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [12] #add#18 at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:69 [inlined]
 [13] add(::String) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:69
 [14] top-level scope at none:0

julia> using Ijulia
ERROR: ArgumentError: Package Ijulia not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Ijulia")` to install the Ijulia package.

Stacktrace:
 [1] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:823
```

Answer (score 1):

Ijulia ではなくIJuliaでした。。。